# Cards in the darkness

Tags: logical-deduction

A man is sitting in a dark room. In front of him is a pile of 100 cards. He knows that there are 90 cards faced up and 10 cards faced down. 
Is it possible for the man to form two piles from these cards such that each pile contains the same number of faced down cards? No loopholes...

Comment: That's impossible! You can't make a pile of 10 cards faced down into 50 cards faced down! What exactly does: _separate those two piles into two piles_ mean?

Comment: Depending which side a card shows it is called faced up or faced down. For example each card has a red and a blue side. 
If you pick up a card and you can its red side, then it is called faced up and faced down otherwise..

Comment: @Bob I think the man can flip face-down cards into face-up cards and visa versa.

Comment: I really, really hope this isn't a lateral thinking puzzle where the solution is "Turn on the lights." It's really interesting if it's *not* one; if it is, then that's pretty weak.

Comment: To be honest I don't understand, why a question/riddle puzzle becomes less interesting, if someone tells you, that he/she didn't want to hear that solution or wanted to hear a different one.. well, one can propose the solution of turning the lights, however I don't see any value in it or why it should be an "interesting" solution/answer..

Comment: What precisely do you mean by "*each containing 50 cards which are either all faced up or down*"? We have to form two piles and each pile must be all up or all down?

Comment: Is this what you meant to ask? http://puzzles.nigelcoldwell.co.uk/thirtysix.htm

Comment: @Quark I don't think so, since that puzzle doesn't specify how many cards have to be in each pile. I think the point is that you have 100 cards (10 up, 90 down) and you have to flip them so that you have 50 up, 50 down.

Comment: I assume he has to *know* that the cards are right and stop? If not, he can just spend eternity flipping cards in every permutation, right? Eventually he'll hit a "correct" state, even if he doesn't know it.

Comment: @Gerhard I don't think your edit was accurate. I interpreted the question as "There are 90 cards face up, and 10 face down. The man must split the cards into 2 piles of 50 where each pile is either all face up or all face down."

Comment: @mdc32 your interpretation matches what was asked, but that problem is not solvable. You're being asked to align the states of multiple cards without any knowledge of their current states.

Answer (score 28):

Assuming Gerhard's edit reflects what the OP *meant* to ask, then yes.

> Take 10 cards from the deck. You now have a stack of 10 cards with n face down cards and a stack of 90 cards with 10-n face down cards. Now turn the stack of 10 over, to give you 10-n face down cards.

Comment: @MaskedMan why not? You take the top ten cards and flip them: in your example this would give all 100 cards facing up.

Answer (score 6):

And out-of-the-box solution.

> Make 2 roughly equal piles and place them standing one against the other.  No card faces down, they all face the one or the other side.

Answer (score 5):

> Arbitrarily (randomly)
> divide the pile (or deck) of cards into two piles of $90$ and $10$. 
> \begin{array}{lcl}\text{Status}&\text{Pile1}&\text{Pile2}\\\text{Total cards}&90&~~10\\\text{Total face-down}&x&~~10-x\hskip1in\end{array}
>
> Now flip all cards in Pile2 to get equal number of face-down cards in both piles. 
>
> \begin{array}{lcl}\text{Status}&\text{Pile1}&\text{Pile2}\\\text{Total cards}&90&~~10\\\text{Total face-down}&x&~~10-(10-x) = x\end{array}

Comment: isn't this what frodoskywalker already answered?

Answer (score 2):

The key is you have to make any two piles, doesn't necessarily 50/50

Lets call $C = 100$ the number of cards 
and $N = 90$ number of face up

For simplicity imagine $N = 1$

You take 1 card at random from the $C$ pile now you have a $pile A = 99$ cards and $pile B = 1$ card

Now you flip the card in $B$ two scenarios occurs 
$\cdot$If card $B$ is the face up mean $A$ doesnt have any face up cards after the flip $A$ and $B$ have 0 face up cards 
$\cdot$if card $B$ is face down mean $A$ have 1 face up cards after the flip $A$ and $B$ have 1 face up card

The Generalised Case

There are $N$ face up cards in Pile 1. We take $N$ cards from Pile 1 to form Pile 2. Lets say, by chance $F$ of those are face up. This necessarily leaves $N-F$ face up cards in Pile 1.

Pile 2 contains $N$ cards, $F$ of which are face up, meaning $N-F$ are face down. When we flip over Pile 2 these $N-F$ face down card become face up. Both piles contain $N-F$ face up cards.

Answer (score 0):

First he builds two piles by dealing one card at a time.
(0,0), (1,0), (1,1), (2,1)...(50,50).

After this, he puts one pile onto the other (without shuffling) and repeats the process, but he is then dealing a different number of cards.

The idea is to follow 1*2*2*5*5 = 100. In other words:

First round, 1 card per pile.
Second round, 2 cards per pile.
...
Last round, 5 cards per pile.

---

I tried it and it worked. Maybe I was lucky since I have no idea why it worked (if it does).

Comment: Is this method intended to produce the correct piles eventually, at some unknown time?

Comment: I was thinking about how many times you have to repeat the process in order to make sure. There is maybe a connection to 1*2*2*5*5 = 100.

Comment: But is this intended to produce the desired result at the end of the process, or at *some* point in the process?

Comment: There is a process with a certain amount of moves. After all the moves were executed, the piles are prepared.

Comment: Can you explain how this prepares the piles?

Comment: Check the edited answer. I hope you can understand my weird thoughts. Trying to write a programm for that, but I kind of suck at programming :D

Comment: I understand what you're saying, but you don't give any reason **why** you think this will work.

Comment: Sorry but this does not work. Imagine a pile of cards where the last 10 cards are face down. After the first round, you end up with 2 piles with 5 face down cards each `(5, 5)`. After round 2 `(5, 5)`, followed by `(7, 3)`, `(4, 6)` and finally `(4, 6)`.